# AngularJs Http Post not Posting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

On button press, no action happens on the browser and there is no new user at my REST endpoint. registerUser() is triggered by button press. I closely followed a tutorial.

The html partial

```
<div class="section no-pad-bot" ng-controller="registerController" id="index-banner">
```

blah blah blah then

```
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" input-field col s6 offset-s3">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                            <input type="text" class="validate" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" input-field col s6 offset-s3">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                            <input type="text" class="validate" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" input-field col s6 offset-s3">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_lock</i>
                            <input type="text" class="validate" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" ng-click="registerUser()">Submit
                                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                </button>
                </form>
```

In the clientapp.js

```
myApp.controller('registerController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.registerUser = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON
            var data = $.param({
                hashword: $scope.password,
                username: $scope.username,
                email: $scope.email,
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post('/api/users', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("successful post");
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("failed post");
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                    "<hr />status: " + status +
                    "<hr />headers: " + header +
                    "<hr />config: " + config;
            });
        };
```

Comment: I don't see `user` object in your scope, change `ng-model="user.email"` to ng-model="email" similarly `ng-model="user.username"` to `ng-model="username"` and `ng-model="user.password"` to `ng-model="password"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in html page, you are referring `user.username`, 'user.email' and `user.password` instead of `username`, `email` and `password` respectivbely.

Try to change to following

```
<input type="text" class="validate" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" class="validate" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" class="validate" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but still for some reason, the mouse click of the button does nothing

Comment: Sorry, does nothing means ? Try to see payload in Developer Console of browser.